# The bulk data source does not support the SQLNUMERIC or SQLDECIMAL data types

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using BCP to export and import data but it seems that SQLNUMERIC or SQLDECIMAL data types are not supported. Exporting seems to be fine:

```
-- hit alt+Q then M to enable SQLCMD mode
use tempdb
go
create table mytest (a decimal);
insert mytest values (3.3);
-- export to c drive
!!bcp "tempdb..mytest" out "c:\mytest.dat" -T -n -S"YourServer\YourInstance" 
!!bcp "tempdb..mytest" format nul -T -n  -f "c:\mytest.fmt" -S"YourServer\YourInstance" 

GO
```

That works okay, but when I then go to import the data back (like this):

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM OPENROWSET( 
    BULK 'C:\mytest.dat', 
    FORMATFILE = 'C:\mytest.fmt') AS a
```

I get the error message:

```
Msg 4838, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The bulk data source does not support the SQLNUMERIC or SQLDECIMAL data types.
```

**Question** How can I import numeric data that was exported using BCP?
I have control over the bcp commands shown in this question, but not the table definitions. A T-SQL only solution is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the "native" format, I tried with the character one ("-c") and it worked. The modified script which I used was:

```
use tempdb 
go 
create table mytest (id int, t varchar(12), a decimal(18,2), c char); 
insert mytest values (1, 'test1', 3.6, 'a');
insert mytest values (2, 'test3', 3.3, 'b');
go 
!!bcp "tempdb..mytest" out "d:\temp\mytest.dat" -T -c -S"localhost"  
!!bcp "tempdb..mytest" format nul -T -c  -f "d:\temp\mytest.fmt" -S"localhost"  

GO 

select * from mytest

SELECT a.*  
FROM OPENROWSET(  
    BULK 'd:\temp\mytest.dat',
    FORMATFILE = 'd:\temp\mytest.fmt') AS a
```

I am not sure if it's feasible in your case but you can give it a try.

Comment: This is super! And it looks promising!